# findViewById vs local reference in Activity

Tags: android, performance

Would it be there noticeable speed improvement if I would create local references to needed view elements (e.g. `EditText` or `Button`) in my activity (in `onCreate()`) and use them for accessing needed elements or it does not much matter if I always use `findViewById()` when I need to access some particular element?

Comment: as @Karlo pointed out, findViewById is far more expensive than local reference. you can check out the detail in this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/_22Z90dshoM especially the answers from Dianne Hackborn , the Android framework engineer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a ListActivity this is what the View Holder pattern advocates.  I would say it depends on how often the view is getting refreshed.

Here's a video and pdf from Google I/O which talks about implementing a ViewHolder pattern in the getView method of a ListAdapter

[The world of ListView](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but let me post my answer for anyone who happen to be curious just as me: at least in api level 17 (4.2.2), DFS (Depth First Search) is used to look for a view, and no caching mechanism exists (meaning search will be repeated every time you call `findViewById()`).

Answer (score 3):

It will be a speed improvement if you have a complex layout and you are accessing those `View`s too often. It is a good practice to define private variables and to bind them to the references returned by `findViewById` once in `onCreate()` then accessing them throughout your code.

If you are accessing those Views just once for, let's say, adding OnClickListeners to them, I don't think it is needed to create local references, as you call them.