# the best way to access gui elements

Tags: android, coding-style, android-widget

currently I use this way (more times in the class ) to access the gui elements

```
((RadioButton)findViewById( R.id.STORAGE_RG_0 )).setEnabled(false);
```

or is it better to fill a variable

```
RadioButton bla = ((RadioButton)findViewById( R.id.STORAGE_RG_0 ));
bla.setEnabled(false);
```

and how can i measure the performance ?

thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [findViewById vs local reference in Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064437/findviewbyid-vs-local-reference-in-activity)

Comment: And one another possible duplicate: [Android Efficiency - Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430557/android-efficiency-views)

Answer (score 0):

Finding view by ID requires a call and walking down view hierarchy -  so clearly there is performance penalty as comparedto variable acces.